# How do I replace a string with integers in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, array.prototype.map

So I have an array of objects :

```
var arr = [
    {name: 'John', cars: '2', railcard: 'yes', preferences: ['taxi', 'tram', 'walking']},
    {name: 'Mary', cars: '0', railcard: 'no', preferences: ['cyling', 'walking', 'taxi']},
    {name: 'Elon', cars: '100000', railcard: 'no', preferences: ['Falcon 9', 'self-driving', 'Hyper-loop']}
];
```

I'm trying to transform the above array using map, filter, an reduce. I'm having trouble altering the original array even though I can easily isolate a specific data set.

For example:

I'm trying to change the amount of cars owned by each person to be a number and not a string so...

```
var cars = arr.map(function(arr) {return arr.cars});
var carsToNumber = cars.map(function(x) {return parseInt(x)});
```

How do I now replace the original string values in the array?

Expected result:

```
var arr = [
    {name: 'John', cars: 2, railcard: 'yes', preferences: ['taxi', 'tram', 'walking']},
    {name: 'Mary', cars: 0, railcard: 'no', preferences: ['cyling', 'walking', 'taxi']},
    {name: 'Elon', cars: 100000, railcard: 'no', preferences: ['Falcon 9', 'self-driving', 'Hyper-loop']}
];
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: updated with desired result

Comment: There are many syntax errors in your code. Arrays are not closed and some object keys are invalid...

Comment: @Badacadabra correct, I've just updated the example to fix the syntax errors around the name strings and the railcard id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `forEach` loop and change string to number. `map()` method creates a new array.

```js
var arr = [
  {name: 'John', cars: '2', railcard: 'yes', preferences: ['taxi', 'tram', 'walking']},
  {name: 'Mary', cars: '0', railcard: 'no', preferences: ['cyling', 'walking', 'taxi']},
  {name: 'Elon', cars: '100000', railcard: 'no', preferences: ['Falcon 9', 'self-driving', 'Hyper-loop']}
];

arr.forEach(e => e.cars = +e.cars);
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this with `map` would be to return a new copy. If you want to modify the original data, use a simple loop.

`map` example:

```
const updatedArr = arr.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, {cars: +item.cars}))
```

Comment: not true... modifying same object reference that exists in original